# Array as input variable in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which takes input a single value which is a array of integers. This input is not from any table but from a interface. How do I read this array of values in a variable and decode them to seperate columns and insert in to table. I also then need to output  a  single value which is a array of some values.

For Ex : Input =x
    x= 1 100 200 300

I need to read this and input 1 in to a seperate column and 100 in to a seperate column and so forth

I then need to output a variable which is a array of values

For Ex: y=(141,2) where 141 is the unique value for the row . dont worry about 141 and 2 I can figure out how to get those values but how do I output a array of values

I am on SQL 2005

Thanks

Comment: You can not. But, you can input a string of comma delimited items, and parse through the string.

Comment: That would be an AWESOME feature, in my opinion.

Comment: @jp2code - In 2008+ table valued parameters allow you to pass a set of items.

Comment: The tag says 2008 the text says 2005. Which are you using?

Comment: - http://stackoverflow.com/q/7164239/153923

- http://stackoverflow.com/q/167643/153923

- http://stackoverflow.com/q/4720138/153923